# Detect double click on input of type="number" but not when spinner (arrows) are clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following code:

```
 var maxAmount = 9999;
 let $input= $('<input type="number" min="0" max="' + ammaxAmount unt + '">');
 
 $input.dblclick(function() { $input.val(maxAmount ); })
```

My intention is that when someone double clicks the input it's automatically set to the max value. The problem is that if I click fast on the spinner arrows it also sets it to the max value.

Comment: Hide the default arrows and make your own arrows in html

Comment: I'm expecting someone can post a full solution for this, and hopefully without having to do that handcrafted